# Typescript, Babel 7, Karma, Jasmine, Code Coverage Configuration

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, babeljs, karma-coverage

I'm developing a standalone library in Typescript and am trying to setup unit testing and code coverage with Karma, Jasmine, and Babel 7.  I wrote a couple of simple tests and am attempting to have Karma run them, but zero tests are running.  The message `03 08 2019 07:36:35.252:WARN [middleware:karma]: Invalid file type (ts), defaulting to js.` is emitted the console, followed by `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)`.  This is telling me I'm missing something from the Karma config file, but I'm not certain of what the missing piece is.

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'src/**/*.ts'
        ],


        // list of files / patterns to exclude
        exclude: [],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'spec/**/*.spec.ts': ['babel'],
            'src/**/*.ts': ['babel']
        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],

        coverageReporter: {
            reporters: [
                {
                    type: 'html',
                    dir: 'coverage/'
                }
            ]
        },

        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity,
    });
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "sourceMaps": "inline",
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript-preprocessor, pretty sure babel is meant for js only

Comment: @cYrixmorten, that's what I initially thought, but Babel 7 has Typescript support.  Prior to adding `@babel/typescript`, I would receive Typescript compilation errors, so it appears as though Karma is running Babel, and compiling Typescript, but Karma doesn't see Babel's output.

Comment: According to https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/ you somehow need to pass `--extensions '.ts'` to babel, not sure if it will be picked up by passing it to karma. Anyway might be the missing link.

Comment: ever figure this out?  I'm hitting the same issue here